# Can't scroll on the results when I test the endpoint on rapidapi

Tags: yahoo-finance, rapidapi

When I test the endpoint with some API (this time yahoo finance API) I can't scroll on the results and all it show's is the max the little box can go. I know this might sound like a stupid question, but I literally cannot work with the API because I can't see what there is and what I can and can't get from it.

[image]

As you can see in the pic all I can see is what fits and for some reason it doesn't let me scroll(everything was fine when I started working with it)
Is this a problem on my end or should I just change browsers or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some unknown glitch, maybe from the browser. Here are a few steps that can fix the scrolling issue:

1. Try refreshing the webpage.
2. Reset your browser - `Go to settings -> Advanced (at the bottom of the page) -> Restore settings`
3. Turn off hardware acceleration - `Go to setting -> Advanced (at the bottom of the page) -> Scroll to the “System” section and toggle “Use hardware acceleration when available`
4. You can switch to the other browser if it's still not working after trying above steps.